# tkinter rewriting text after variable changes

Tags: python, tkinter

I have this code. I remove import tkinter and import Project and other code for easy reading.

```
from Project import *

class TechnologyIDE:
    def __init__(self, master):
        #Vytvoření master
        self.master = master

        #Settings Tk
        master.title('Technology IDE')

        #Frame
        frame = Frame(root)
        frame.pack()

        self.frameLEFT = Frame(master)
        self.frameLEFT.pack(side=LEFT,fill=Y)

        self.frameRIGHT = Frame(master)
        self.frameRIGHT.pack(side=RIGHT, expand=True, fill=BOTH)

        #Vytvoření menu
        menu = Menu(master)
        root.config(menu=menu)

        #Boxy
        self.showCodewitHLines()
        self.showProjectToolbar()
        self.showNavigator()

    def showProjectToolbar(self):
        actualProject = project.actualProject
        listbox = Listbox(self.frameLEFT, width=50)
        listbox.pack(side=TOP, anchor=W)
        if actualProject == "":
            listbox.insert(END, "None project opened")
        else:
            print("Vidim"+actualProject)
            listbox.delete(0, END)
            listbox.insert(END, actualProject)
            var = os.listdir(actualProject+"/")
            for va in var :
                listbox.insert(END,"    "+va)

    def showCodewitHLines(self):
        TextArea = Text()
        ScrollBar = Scrollbar(root)
        ScrollBar.config(command=TextArea.yview)
        TextArea.config(yscrollcommand=ScrollBar.set)
        ScrollBar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
        TextArea.pack(expand=True, fill='both')

    def showNavigator(self):
        listbox = Listbox(self.frameLEFT,width=50)
        listbox.pack(side=TOP, anchor=W)
        listbox.insert(END, "NAVIGATOR")


    root = Tk()
    ide = TechnologyIDE(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

and I have this code in my Project.py

```
class Project:
    def __init__(self):
        self.actualProject = ""

    def newProject(self):
        self.top = Toplevel()
        self.top.title("Creating new project")
        self.top.focus_set()

        self.projectname = Entry(self.top)
        self.projectname.pack()

        btnClose = Button(self.top, text="Close", command=self.top.destroy)
        btnCreate = Button(self.top, text="Create", command=self.createProject)
        btnCreate.pack()
        btnClose.pack()

    def createProject(self):
        self.newpath = "Projects/"+self.projectname.get()
        if not os.path.exists(self.newpath):
            os.makedirs(self.newpath)
            fn = open(self.newpath+"/"+"run.py", "w+")
            self.top.destroy()
            self.actualProject = self.newpath
            print("Project"+self.actualProject)

project = Project()
```

And I have this problem.
When I create new project which is succesfully created I see it in files. I want it to be loaded into gui (showProjectToolbar). So I create new project, it should load into variable and that gui is in loop so it should loaded and visible in the gui but it never is.
I am giving u photo here for better understanding
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't create and pack a `Listbox` every time `showProjectToolbar` is being called.

Create it in `TechnologyIDE`'s `__def__` function, like that:

```
self.listbox = Listbox(self.frameLEFT, width=50)
self.listbox.pack(side=TOP, anchor=W)
```

Then, when you create a new project, just add it: `self.listbox.insert(END, actualProject)`.

Comment: changed but still the same bug

Comment: Have you tried debugging the outcome? Does the addition even gets executed? I'm gonna need more info than that.

Comment: I am recoding that project so i have not the code availible. But there was problem that actualProject wasnt visible